# ASP.NET SignalR C# Client App Exception on Start

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a ASP.NET application. I run it by hitting debug. It runs on localhost:2842.

I have a SignalR Hub defined in a class with no methods on the server.

I have a WPF Windows C# application. I added the SignalR NuGet package. I use the following code to instantiate the client proxy:

```
        var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:2842");

        IHubProxy myHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
        myHubProxy.On<string>("SendMeData", dataString => {

            Console.WriteLine("String value {0}", dataString);
        });

        hubConnection.Start().Wait();
```

Here is my hub class defined on the server:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public static void SendMeData(string dataString)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
        if (context != null)
            context.Clients.All.SendMeData(dataString);
    }
}
```

I have this code in Startup.cs:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);

        app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
        {
            EnableDetailedErrors = true
        });
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that when the C# client calls hubConnection.Start().Wait(); I get a very unhelpful exception. Here is the exception:

```
StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content:
System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcTXlEZXZcUmVhbHRpbWVNRFxSZWFsdGltZU1EUHJvdG9cUmVhbHRpbWVNRFByb3RvXHNpZ25hbHJcbmVnb3RpYXRl?=
Cache-Control: private  Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2017 04:23:18 GMT  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I set break points in the server code and it never hits any of them.

How do I figure this out?

Comment: Turn on developer exceptions to see the stack trace or turn on breaking on first chance exceptions and debug the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole problem ended up being that I had changed the name of my Hub class in the server without changing the name used in CreateHubProxy. it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

In your MyHub class, you've got the following line:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
        if (context != null)
```

Get rid of this. Instead your MyHub class should be:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public static void SendMeData(string dataString)
    {
       Clients.All.SendMeData(dataString);
    }
}
```

GetHubContext is used for getting a reference to a Hub from another class within the same AppDomain. For example, if you are in a Controller class and need to call a method on a Hub within the same AppDomain, you would get a reference to the Hub via GetHubContext.

Also in your client code, please remove the .Wait(). The code should be

```
await hubConnection.Start();
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#how-to-define-methods-in-the-hub-class-that-clients-can-call)

Comment: Clients is not static. How do I get access to Clients without an object pointer? I need to be able to send data to the clients from inside a meeting controller using SendMeData.

Comment: Clients is a dynamic property of the Hub. You may not get Intellisense support, but code will compile. You can see it as a property in the SignalR source code here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/2.2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hub.cs

Comment: I changed my code to what you specified and got the following compiler error: error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Hub.Clients'

Comment: Without your full source to see where the error is, I'm not sure where your issue is. But you can see a very good video that talks about the Hub class, the Clients dynamic property and how it's used at https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/implementing-two-way-communication-with-signalr-8358?l=DFewtjFz_3304984382. Go to module 1: Introduction to SignalR, then skip to the SignalR Hubs bookmark within the section.

Comment: My code is above in the original post. The error is on the line that you told me to change to using the Clients property. That is because you can see my method is marked as static so that I can call this method without having an instantiated copy of my class. I did it that way so I could call the method on the class directly from a controller. That is why originally I used the GetHubContext because as you said that is used to make calls to a hub from within a controller for example.

Comment: My code in that part of the app seems to run fine. My real problem is in my client code that is trying to connect to the server. Do you have any thoughts on that part?

Comment: Yeah, in your client method, don't use .Wait(). The code should be "await hubConnection.Start();" Mark your containing method signature as async.

Comment: I can't make the calling method async because it is the constructor on my window class, but I don't think that matters because I am not doing anything after. Also, I thought await in an async method was the same as .Wait(). Guess I was wrong. At least this got rid of the exception. Now it runs. The problem is it doesn't work. Please post your answer of taking .Wait off to fix the exception and I will mark it as the answer. If you can give any thoughts on why my SendMeData method is never called in the client that would be awesome!!

Comment: Arg. Turns out that didn't actually fix the problem. I was doing this whole thing in my MainWindow constructor, so I just removed the .Wait from the end and it "seemed" fix the problem because I don't get the exception anymore. Well, it still wasn't working so I decided to make a whole new method and call that method from a menu item in my gui. I made this new method async, like you suggested and put await in front of the hubConnection.Start(). I am getting the same exception again, so we are still not there yet. Why am I getting an exception here?

Comment: Never mind. I figured out the problem. At some point I had changed the name of my hub and forgot to change the name of the hub proxy in CreateHubProxy. My Bad. Closing this question as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

There're probably two reasons for this symptom:

1. The hub name is not found, or misspelled.
2. The hub class is not public.

Anyway, the SignalR library is too bad to not pointing out the real cause, with only a 500 code in error!!